# Class 'app\routing' not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm currently building an application that will require a few different name spaces, however most of the application I want to put under the app namespace.

In my index.php file I declared to use the app namespace, however PHP still insists my class cannot be found like so...

```
<?php

define('PATH',strtok ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , '?' ));
define("ROOT",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/',true);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'app/class_loader.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;
use app\routing;

$routing = new routing;
$routing->router();
```

and inside my routing class I declare it as part of the app namespace like this

```
<?php
namespace app;

class routing
{
```

However I keep getting `Fatal error: Class 'app\routing' not found in /var/www/my_app/index.php on line 15`

This is my autoload file

```
<?php
function autoload_class_multiple_directory($class_name)
{

    # List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_paths = array(
        'app/controllers',
        'app/models',
        'app/services',
    );

    foreach($array_paths as $path)
    {
        $file = $path.'/'.$class_name.'.php';
        if(is_file($file))
        {
            include $file;
        }

    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_class_multiple_directory');
```

I thought this is how namespaces worked? I want to ensure I make my application as easy to follow and code in from the get-go, could somebody please help point me in the right direction?

cheers!

Comment: **AFAIK** you don't need the `use [...]` you can just do `$routing = new app\routing;`. Also please show us your autoload function just in case you are doing something wrong in that.

Comment: I Still get the same issue

Comment: @Script47 I've updated my question with the autoload file